# Smart home 2-way communication like Google home hub and Nest hello

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there a trait to implement real-time 2-way communication with Google Smart home like Google home hub and Nest hello 2-way audio video?
I'm trying to develop the app which can support 2-way audio video with google home.
What kinds of protocols should I support for 2-way audio video?

Comment: No there is no trait for that.